# How to convert a comma separated string with each word enclosed in quotes ' ' to a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to convert comma separated string, with each word enclosed in a ' ' to a list in python . I am fetching this from a database and when I checked its type it says it is a string.I used the existing answers. The problem I am facing is that after the list is constructed it is enclosing the existing ' ' with a double quote . For example my string is

`s = 'a' , 'b' , 'c'`.  So i used

`s = s.split(',')` or `list.append(s)`

As an output I get

```
[" 'a' ", " 'b' ", " 'c' "]
```

also I get few unwanted characters like \ \ for some strings.

I just simply want to convert

```
s = 'a' , 'b' , 'c'
```

to `[a,b,c]` or `['a','b', 'c']`

`json.loads()` and literal eval are raising exceptions due to some unwanted characters in some strings . Can anyone help me please ? Thank you.

Here is my repr, not printing the complete repr
'\'type="button\', \'div\', \'type="submit\', \'OneWeb\', \'Softbank Group\', \'Qualcomm Global Tradingwith\', \'Company\', \'Court\', \'Arianespace\', \'OneWeb Satellites\', \'Airbus\', \'Intelsat\', \'LEO\', \'LEO/GEO\', \'SoftBank Group\', \'SoftBank\', \'Company\', \'Court\', \'OneWeb\', \'U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Softbank\', \'Arianespace\', \'Qualcomm Technologies\', \'Deloitte Touche Tohmatsu\', \'Hughes Network Systems\', \'Deutsche Bank\', \'Viasat\', \'Nokia\', \'Rockwell Collins\', \'USSI Global\', \'Qualcomm\', \'1111 Ventures LLC\', \'Airbus\', \'Globalstar\', \'Orbcomm\', \'Teledesic\', \'OneWeb\', \'U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'the Financial Times\', \'SoftBank\', \'WeWork\', \'Virgin Group\', \'Qualcomm\', \'Airbus\', \'Intelsat\', \'Hughes Communications\', \'Grupo Salinas\', \'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Arianespace\', \'Soyuz\', \'Steckel\', \'Musk\', \'SpaceX\', \'Starlink\', \'Amazon\', \'OneWeb Satellites\', \'Gingiss\', \'JavaScript\', , \'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Company\', \'OneWeb\', \'the Bankruptcy Court\', \'Court\', \'Milbank LLP\', \'FTI Consulting\', \'Guggenheim Securities\', \'LLC\''"'OneWeb', 'U.S. Bankruptcy Court', 'the Financial Times', 'SoftBank', 'WeWork', 'Virgin Group', 'Qualcomm', 'Airbus', 'Intelsat', 'Hughes Communications', 'Grupo Salinas', 'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court', 'Arianespace', 'Soyuz', 'Steckel', 'Musk', 'SpaceX', 'Starlink', 'Amazon', 'OneWeb Satellites', 'Gingiss', 'the Gravity Gradient Stabilization Experiment', 'IRAS', 'the Harvard-Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics', 'GGSE-4', 'SSO', 'SpaceX', 'Starlink', 'Musk', 'The U.S. Air Force', 'LeoLabs', 'the University of Pittsburgh', 'NASA', 'U.S. National Reconnaissance Office', 'McDowell', 'Scientific American', 'NASA', 'SpaceX',

**Edited answer:**
Taking a clue from below answer by Mohammaed Shabir , I used strip(" ") and again strip("'") to get the answer, hence I will accept the answer below. The problem in below answer was it was replacing the words containing apostrophe as well like your's.

***Here is my solution***
s1 = '''  '\'type="button\', \'div\', \'type="submit\', \'OneWeb\', \'Softbank Group\', \'Qualcomm Global Tradingwith\', \'Company\', \'Court\', \'Arianespace\', \'OneWeb Satellites\', \'Airbus\', \'Intelsat\', \'LEO\', \'LEO/GEO\', \'SoftBank Group\', \'SoftBank\', \'Company\', \'Court\', \'OneWeb\', \'U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Softbank\', \'Arianespace\', \'Qualcomm Technologies\', \'Deloitte Touche Tohmatsu\', \'Hughes Network Systems\', \'Deutsche Bank\', \'Viasat\', \'Nokia\', \'Rockwell Collins\', \'USSI Global\', \'Qualcomm\', \'1111 Ventures LLC\', \'Airbus\', \'Globalstar\', \'Orbcomm\', \'Teledesic\', \'OneWeb\', \'U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'the Financial Times\', \'SoftBank\', \'WeWork\', \'Virgin Group\', \'Qualcomm\', \'Airbus\', \'Intelsat\', \'Hughes Communications\', \'Grupo Salinas\', \'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Arianespace\', \'Soyuz\', \'Steckel\', \'Musk\', \'SpaceX\', \'Starlink\', \'Amazon\', \'OneWeb Satellites\', \'Gingiss\', \'JavaScript\', , \'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Company\', \'OneWeb\', \'the Bankruptcy Court\', \'Court\', \'Milbank LLP\', \'FTI Consulting\', \'Guggenheim Securities\', \'LLC\''"'OneWeb', 'U.S. Bankruptcy Court', 'the Financial Times', 'SoftBank', 'WeWork', 'Virgin Group', 'Qualcomm', 'Airbus', 'Intelsat', 'Hughes Communications', 'Grupo Salinas', 'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court', 'Arianespace', 'Soyuz', 'Steckel', 'Musk', 'SpaceX', 'Starlink', 'Amazon', 'OneWeb Satellites', 'Gingiss', 'the Gravity Gradient Stabilization Experiment', 'IRAS', 'the Harvard-Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics', 'GGSE-4', 'SSO', 'SpaceX', 'Starlink', 'Musk', 'The U.S. Air Force', 'LeoLabs', 'the University of Pittsburgh', 'NASA', 'U.S. National Reconnaissance Office', 'McDowell', 'Scientific American', 'NASA', 'SpaceX', '''

```
ls = s1.split(",")
ls = [i.strip(" ") for i in ls]
ls = [i.strip("'") for i in ls]
print(ls)
```

Though there are couple of words intermediately which still displays the spaces.

Comment: If `s = 'a' , 'b' , 'c'` then `s` is `tuple` already. I guess you meant `s = "'a' , 'b' , 'c'"` this?

Comment: But when I print its type it says string , I am getting this from a database @Ch3steR

Comment: How does `s` look like when you `print(repr(s))`

Comment: You could do `print(repr(s))` and find out what it really is.

Comment: It is getting added with some \\ like \'a'\ for some strings

Comment: Why don't you copy-paste the `print(repr(s))` output here. So it becomes easy for us to help.

Comment: That is still way to vague. We need to see what the data looks like to help.

Comment: Does it look like this `'\'a\' , \'b\' , \'c\''`?

Comment: It is on a remote server and ctrl c doesn't seem to have any effect on command prompt @Ch3steR

Comment: Yes for few strings @Ch3steR

Comment: If we don't know how your data looks like, it really impossible to help. From the question `s` is a `tuple` but you claim it's `string` and you aren't showing `repr(s)`. From this limited info you won't get a concrete answer.

Comment: @Ch3steR let me try to print it in a file and see if I can get it

Comment: @Ch3steR I have added a portion of repr(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable `s` is a tuple hence we can convert it into list using `list(s)`try this code.,

```
s = 'a' , 'b' , 'c'
print(list(s))
>>>['a', 'b', 'c']
```

### EDIT 1

If the variable `s` is of type string we can convert it into a list using list comprehension.Hope it helps.

```
s = "'a' , 'b' , 'c'"
ls = [i for i in s if i.isalpha()]
print(ls)
```

### EDIT 2

since in the updated question variable `s` may contain `" , ' ,\` and lengthy strings thus in order to make a list from the string. try ,

```
s = '''  '\'type="button\', \'div\', \'type="submit\', \'OneWeb\', \'Softbank Group\', \'Qualcomm Global Tradingwith\', \'Company\', \'Court\', \'Arianespace\', \'OneWeb Satellites\', \'Airbus\', \'Intelsat\', \'LEO\', \'LEO/GEO\', \'SoftBank Group\', \'SoftBank\', \'Company\', \'Court\', \'OneWeb\', \'U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Softbank\', \'Arianespace\', \'Qualcomm Technologies\', \'Deloitte Touche Tohmatsu\', \'Hughes Network Systems\', \'Deutsche Bank\', \'Viasat\', \'Nokia\', \'Rockwell Collins\', \'USSI Global\', \'Qualcomm\', \'1111 Ventures LLC\', \'Airbus\', \'Globalstar\', \'Orbcomm\', \'Teledesic\', \'OneWeb\', \'U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'the Financial Times\', \'SoftBank\', \'WeWork\', \'Virgin Group\', \'Qualcomm\', \'Airbus\', \'Intelsat\', \'Hughes Communications\', \'Grupo Salinas\', \'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Arianespace\', \'Soyuz\', \'Steckel\', \'Musk\', \'SpaceX\', \'Starlink\', \'Amazon\', \'OneWeb Satellites\', \'Gingiss\', \'JavaScript\', , \'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court\', \'Company\', \'OneWeb\', \'the Bankruptcy Court\', \'Court\', \'Milbank LLP\', \'FTI Consulting\', \'Guggenheim Securities\', \'LLC\''"'OneWeb', 'U.S. Bankruptcy Court', 'the Financial Times', 'SoftBank', 'WeWork', 'Virgin Group', 'Qualcomm', 'Airbus', 'Intelsat', 'Hughes Communications', 'Grupo Salinas', 'the U.S. Bankruptcy Court', 'Arianespace', 'Soyuz', 'Steckel', 'Musk', 'SpaceX', 'Starlink', 'Amazon', 'OneWeb Satellites', 'Gingiss', 'the Gravity Gradient Stabilization Experiment', 'IRAS', 'the Harvard-Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics', 'GGSE-4', 'SSO', 'SpaceX', 'Starlink', 'Musk', 'The U.S. Air Force', 'LeoLabs', 'the University of Pittsburgh', 'NASA', 'U.S. National Reconnaissance Office', 'McDowell', 'Scientific American', 'NASA', 'SpaceX', '''
ls = s.split(", ")
out = [i.replace("'","") for i in ls]
print(out)
```

Comment: Since `s.split(',')` didn't raise an error, `s` isn't a tuple. OP hasn't done a good job of showing input and we can't really answer til he does.

Comment: @tdelaney s is a string when i do type(s) it says a string. I am fetching it from database.

Comment: I used the edited code and it is separating each character rather than word.

Comment: Please see my edited question I have added repr() of the input

Comment: Thanks for the update, but will it remove all the quotes from the string " ' " or the starting quote only ? What if there are words like your's . I had used it earlier ?

Comment: Hi taking a clue from this answer I changed it to strip (), and it worked. Thanks